# Running company emails at two different suppliers

Tags: email, exchange

Quick question regarding Exchange:

We are a small company and have had our mail service hosted through Unoeuro until now. Now we have decided to move some of our mail accounts to Exchange because we would like the better service and more options. However, we would still like to keep some of our email addresses at Unoeuro due to price (employees who are not involved full time and just need a basic email account).

I have now spent a couple of hours setting up my own mail account in Office 365 (but we are still using Unoeuro’s nameservers so I’ve added CNAME, SRV etc. to the Unoeuro DNS) and it seems like my account is running fine. The other employees in the company can still use their emails through Unoeuro. However, I have one problem now – I can’t send emails internally now!

When I send an internal mail I get an error message that my mail couldn’t be delivered and that “XX” wasn’t found at “mydomain.com” (the mail I try to email is XX@mydomain.com).

How do I solve this issue if it can be solved at all?

Comment: I haven't the time to write up a proper answer, but one can configure dual-delivery or forwarding on a per-account basis. One provider will obviously need to be the "primary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when you configure your domain `@domain.com` in your email system, they typically assume they are completely **authoritative** for the entire namespace. In other words, they are the ultimate authority on whether to accept and deliver mail addressed to `<anyone>@domain.com`.

In this scenario, you have two independent email systems, with different (non-intersecting) user lists. We need to ensure each system is aware of users on the other system, so as not to reject legitimate email.

---

## Internal delivery

At the moment, sending mail from users on one mail system to the other will fail. When the mail system doesn't know the other mail system exists, it will throw mail destined for users on that system away and send a bounce to you to indicate the user doesn't exist:

[image: Mail sent to the other mail system will get thrown away and a bounce message generated.]

To remedy this, you need a shared SMTP namespace, so that messages are freely exchanged between both mail systems. The only time they get discarded will be if neither system knows whether the recipient exists:

[image: Email is freely exchanged between the mail systems working in harmony, and thrown away with a bounce message if neither system knows of the recipient.]

In Office 365, you need to configure your `domain.com` as an **internal relay domain**. Per the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/jj945194(v=exchg.150).aspx), an internal relay domain is used when:

> recipients for this domain can be in Office 365 or your own email servers. Email is delivered to known recipients in Office 365 or is relayed to your own email server if the recipients aren’t known to Office 365.

You can find a detailed guide for configuring this online at the [Office 365 community site](https://community.office365.com/en-us/w/exchange/simple-domain-sharing-for-smtp-email-addresses). In this case, "A. Datum Corporation" refers to your Unoeuro mail system, while Office 365 is Office 365 as written.

Unoeuro will subsequently need to be configured to forward email to Office 365. This can be done in a couple of ways:

1. A central configuration on the Unoeuro mail server which directs it to pass email destined to unknown users to Office 365 for further processing. Care is required with this wildcard approach, as it means the Unoeuro server doesn't explicitly know about *every* user with `@domain.com` email addresses. When it doesn't know about an address, it must ask Office 365 for a final deliver/bounce determination, rather than making that decision locally. Therefore, care must be taken to avoid mail loops, and (for email received from external sources) [NDR backscatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email)). I won't consider this approach further here.
2. Individual forwards on a per-mailbox basis at Unoeuro, which cause mail sent to `office365user@domain.com` to be forwarded to `office365user@domain.onmicrosoft.com`. `domain.onmicrosoft.com` is your Office 365 tenant domain, which will force delivery to the Office 365 mailbox.

The article linked above adopts approach number 2. For simplicity, I would recommend this approach, unless you have a significant number of users.

## External delivery

The remaining part to discuss is external delivery of email.

Your `MX` record is the heart of your external email system. It instructs external mail systems what machine(s) are responsible for handling mail `@domain.com`. At the moment, you indicate your `MX` record points to Unoeuro.

At the moment, your `MX` situation looks like this:

[image: MX record delivery,]

Outside servers have no knowledge of your Office 365 environment. They will continue to deliver inbound email to Unoeuro's systems as present. The configuration made for internal email delivery between the two systems (above) will also apply to external email, causing that mail to be forwarded over to Office 365 for users resident there.

You may have other DNS records configured for security purposes, such as a Sender Policy Framework (`SPF`) record. You must ensure these records are updated to approve Office 365 as a trusted sender for mail from `domain.com`, otherwise your mail might be bounced. Talk to Unoeuro if you are unsure.

### Should I add Office 365 as an MX record?

Maybe. You can, but it is not necessary to list both Unoeuro and Office 365. There is additional complexity to this approach, and you must take care to avoid duplicate delivery, mail loops and unknown user scenarios.

Listing both mail systems *may* provide higher uptime; in the event Unoeuro is down, Office 365 users can still receive mail and vice-versa.

I advise that you get this working with a single provider as the inbound `MX` destination initially before expanding to multiple inbound recipients.

Comment: I applaud standing. Went above and beyond, I would propose you for a title - "True IT Guy" of the year.


If you don't mind, what software did you use to create the diagrams?

Comment: @VickVega That's very kind of you to say! I'd like to say I used a very large and complicated piece of software to create the diagrams, but simplicity prevails: they were made with Google Drawing (part of Google Drive).

Comment: Wow that was an amazing and VERY detailed answer. Thank you so much!!! I'm completely overwhelmed. And the best part is...- it actually seems to work :D Once again thanks a million times!